# JQueryValidation - Input error class name

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Is there a way with the [JQueryValidation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to set the input css class error. This css class is different from the label css error class.

Because if I set : `errorClass: "field-validation-error"`

That will apply for label **and** input. I would like input to have "input-validation-error" css class and label to have "field-validation-error" css class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any real reason to support different class names for the error element and the input field itself.

Just use CSS-selectors

```
label.field-validation-error {
  ..whatever styling...
}
input.field-validation-error {
  ..whatever styling...
}
```

This way both have the same css-class applied but get different styling

---

But if you really think you need this than you can use the `highlight` and `unhighlight` options of the validation plugin and wire them up with functions. These can then apply the wanted styles to the element and the error label. In the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) is even a nice example of this which you should be easily able to modify to your needs

Comment: The need to support different class names for the error element and the input field come from the framework I use (Asp.Net MVC 2) that auto-generated the error class name...

Comment: Ok then just use the second approach I described